# Imgix with Wordpress not working for all images

Tags: wordpress, imgix

I have setup Imgix to work with my wordpress site. I have created an Imgix account, and installed the Imgix wordpress plugin, and made the necessary config additions to the wp-config.php file. What these configs do is tell wordpress to serve images via the Imgix domain, instead of the local wordpress asset folder.

The problem I am having is that the only images that will now work via Imgix, are once uploaded via the thumbnail or feature image feature in wordpress. These are showing a url path pointing to Imgix. Whereas assets that are *placed* into a wordpress page are still displaying the normal url path to the assets on my server.

Has anyone experienced this before? I am having a hard time getting to the bottom of why some images are resolving to Imgix, and others are not.